# pinch/zoom gesture with magic mouse 2

Tags: multi-touch, mouse, zoom, gesture

I just purchased a magic mouse 2, and I can't figure out how to do a pinch gesture or its equivalent that I am used to with a macbook.

From what I have read, it doesn't seem like it is possible to do the exact same pinch gesture, but are there alternative gestures or key combinations to get the same zooming capability as the pinch gesture?

Answer (score 1):

You can double tap (not click) to smart zoom.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but it isn't the same as the "pinch gesture" which it does no appear to support so I ordered a magic trackpad 1.0 --- 70$ is pushing it for a fancy mouse.... lol